# How to export rendered pages in jenkins such as the console output with the html markup intact?

Tags: html, plugins, jenkins, file-conversion

The console output (or build log) as visible on the site, contains html markup (mainly from the ansi color plugin), which I intend to export as part of the email notification via email-ext (either as content or attachment). Are there any existing plugins/methods I can use to do this efficiently? I can't think of a better way short of wget + dom parsing, which I find relatively tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the rendered page cannot be fully obtained in the middle of the build through wget (partial javascript code is returned). This probably makes sense, but for my purpose I finally decided to filter the ansi escape sequences from the email (which is possible through build.getLog() + String.replaceAll) so it will be just as readable as the online version.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more helpful if you showed the actual solution you used. i.e. what was the replaceAll sequence you used to strip the escape sequences?

Comment: @catchdave the answer for this question is basically, no it cannot be done etc. There are a number of ways to customize the email however. You can probably find the regex somewhere (I no longer have it)